# My Home/user directory was wiped off from the server, can secure log help finding out how was it done?

Tags: centos

I have a server running on AWS and a cPanel from cpanel.net;
the server is apache and the OS is centos 7
today and suddenly all my 10 websites were not responding and showing 521 error.
After a few minutes of investigation, I came to find out that on my file manager there were no folders/files at all under home/user, all 10 sites, their databases, emails, etc all were gone.
I had a snapshot with amazon so was able to retrieve a backup from the server but kept the old one for investigating.
on the secure log, I can see lots of attempts to connect but I'm not too good at understanding what is going on and how was someone able to connect and delete.
I will paste the log below so someone can help me, please.

Amazon team said that it might be a hacker or could be the Cpanel support team by mistake, but the second option doesn't sound right as professional people wouldn't make such a silly mistake, and also they have confirmed to me that they haven't done it.

I had a dispute with someone who claimed to be a hacker though so not sure if that is the case.

please read this and give any hints to what was going on.
note; all logs before these ones were not there.
And I notice also, commands are executed very frequently, like 3 - 10 commands per one second.

here is it:

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-13-2 log]$ sudo cat secure
    Feb 12 15:19:15 server polkitd[583]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
    Feb 12 15:19:15 server polkitd[583]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
    Feb 12 15:19:15 server polkitd[583]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 2 rules
    Feb 12 15:19:15 server polkitd[583]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
    Feb 12 15:19:20 server sshd[1257]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
    Feb 12 15:19:20 server sshd[1257]: Server listening on :: port 22.
    Feb 12 15:21:22 server sshd[1998]: Invalid user hduser from 111.229.235.119 port 51986
    Feb 12 15:21:22 server sshd[1998]: input_userauth_request: invalid user hduser [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:21:22 server sshd[1998]: Received disconnect from 111.229.235.119 port 51986:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:21:22 server sshd[1998]: Disconnected from 111.229.235.119 port 51986 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:27:12 server polkitd[580]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
    Feb 12 15:27:12 server polkitd[580]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
    Feb 12 15:27:12 server polkitd[580]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 2 rules
    Feb 12 15:27:12 server polkitd[580]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
    Feb 12 15:27:19 server sshd[1297]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
    Feb 12 15:27:19 server sshd[1297]: Server listening on :: port 22.
    Feb 12 15:27:29 server sshd[1833]: Did not receive identification string from 87.251.64.186 port 45362
    Feb 12 15:27:30 server sshd[1835]: Connection closed by 87.251.64.186 port 50330 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:27:30 server sshd[1834]: Invalid user 0101 from 87.251.64.186 port 50108
    Feb 12 15:27:30 server sshd[1834]: input_userauth_request: invalid user 0101 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:27:30 server sshd[1834]: Connection closed by 87.251.64.186 port 50108 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:29:27 server sshd[1987]: Invalid user aaron from 103.37.151.84 port 49382
    Feb 12 15:29:27 server sshd[1987]: input_userauth_request: invalid user aaron [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:29:27 server sshd[1987]: Received disconnect from 103.37.151.84 port 49382:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:29:27 server sshd[1987]: Disconnected from 103.37.151.84 port 49382 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:34:32 server sshd[2234]: Invalid user agustina from 103.45.184.234 port 53762
    Feb 12 15:34:32 server sshd[2234]: input_userauth_request: invalid user agustina [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:34:33 server sshd[2234]: Received disconnect from 103.45.184.234 port 53762:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:34:33 server sshd[2234]: Disconnected from 103.45.184.234 port 53762 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:38:50 server sshd[2578]: Connection closed by 222.119.218.120 port 13597 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:39:31 server sshd[2617]: Accepted publickey for root from 222.119.218.120 port 55062 ssh2: RSA SHA256:cnhuplyGAzI1x1W2DudZZq7CN6qi1oMqTdtdi5VqnRc
    Feb 12 15:39:31 server sshd[2617]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:39:31 server sshd[2617]: pam_lastlog(sshd:session): unable to open /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:39:33 server sshd[2627]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:39:33 server sshd[2627]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:41:59 server sshd[2822]: Received disconnect from 123.58.213.220 port 44408:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:41:59 server sshd[2822]: Disconnected from 123.58.213.220 port 44408 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:42:49 server sshd[2865]: Did not receive identification string from 81.161.63.103 port 44104
    Feb 12 15:42:58 server sshd[2869]: Connection reset by 81.161.63.103 port 43178 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:43:01 server sshd[2867]: Connection reset by 81.161.63.103 port 43168 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:43:01 server sshd[2868]: Connection reset by 81.161.63.103 port 43152 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:43:02 server sshd[2874]: Connection reset by 81.161.63.103 port 43194 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:43:02 server sshd[2877]: Accepted publickey for root from 222.119.218.120 port 16725 ssh2: RSA SHA256:cnhuplyGAzI1x1W2DudZZq7CN6qi1oMqTdtdi5VqnRc
    Feb 12 15:43:03 server sshd[2877]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:43:03 server sshd[2877]: pam_lastlog(sshd:session): unable to open /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:43:04 server sshd[2924]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:43:04 server sshd[2924]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:43:32 server sshd[3150]: Invalid user liangyzh from 190.104.149.194 port 55456
    Feb 12 15:43:32 server sshd[3150]: input_userauth_request: invalid user liangyzh [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:43:32 server sshd[3150]: Received disconnect from 190.104.149.194 port 55456:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:43:32 server sshd[3150]: Disconnected from 190.104.149.194 port 55456 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:46:00 server polkitd[583]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
    Feb 12 15:46:00 server polkitd[583]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
    Feb 12 15:46:00 server polkitd[583]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 2 rules
    Feb 12 15:46:00 server polkitd[583]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
    Feb 12 15:46:10 server sshd[1313]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
    Feb 12 15:46:10 server sshd[1313]: Server listening on :: port 22.
    Feb 12 15:46:31 server sshd[1840]: Accepted publickey for root from 222.119.218.120 port 26665 ssh2: RSA SHA256:cnhuplyGAzI1x1W2DudZZq7CN6qi1oMqTdtdi5VqnRc
    Feb 12 15:46:32 server sshd[1840]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:46:32 server sshd[1840]: pam_lastlog(sshd:session): unable to open /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:46:33 server sshd[1858]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:46:33 server sshd[1858]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:49:59 server sshd[2022]: Connection closed by 90.199.242.27 port 62452 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:50:11 server sshd[2043]: Connection closed by 90.199.242.27 port 62453 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:50:31 server sshd[1840]: Received disconnect from 222.119.218.120 port 26665:11: disconnected by user
    Feb 12 15:50:31 server sshd[1840]: Disconnected from 222.119.218.120 port 26665
    Feb 12 15:50:31 server sshd[1840]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
    Feb 12 15:50:45 server sshd[2096]: Accepted publickey for root from 222.119.218.120 port 37066 ssh2: RSA SHA256:cnhuplyGAzI1x1W2DudZZq7CN6qi1oMqTdtdi5VqnRc
    Feb 12 15:50:45 server sshd[2096]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:50:45 server sshd[2096]: pam_lastlog(sshd:session): unable to open /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:50:46 server sshd[2102]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:50:46 server sshd[2102]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:52:21 server polkitd[583]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2421:38780 (system bus name :1.24 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    Feb 12 15:52:21 server polkitd[583]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2421:38780 (system bus name :1.24, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
    Feb 12 15:56:53 server sshd[2540]: Received disconnect from 85.62.169.71 port 61169:11: Client disconnecting normally [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:56:53 server sshd[2540]: Disconnected from 85.62.169.71 port 61169 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:57:32 server sshd[2096]: Received disconnect from 222.119.218.120 port 37066:11: disconnected by user
    Feb 12 15:57:32 server sshd[2096]: Disconnected from 222.119.218.120 port 37066
    Feb 12 15:57:32 server sshd[2096]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
    Feb 12 15:57:50 server sshd[2767]: Connection closed by 222.119.218.120 port 54211 [preauth]
    Feb 12 15:58:09 server sudo: wp-toolkit : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/wp-toolkit/scripts ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/test -e /etc/passwd
    Feb 12 15:58:09 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:58:09 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Feb 12 15:58:09 server sudo: wp-toolkit : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/wp-toolkit/scripts ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /etc/passwd
    Feb 12 15:58:09 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:58:09 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Feb 12 15:58:09 server sudo: wp-toolkit : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/wp-toolkit/scripts ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /root/.wp-toolkit-identifier
    Feb 12 15:58:09 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:58:09 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Feb 12 15:58:10 server sudo: wp-toolkit : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/wp-toolkit/scripts ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c whmapi1 get_domain_info --output=json
    Feb 12 15:58:10 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:58:10 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Feb 12 15:58:10 server sudo: wp-toolkit : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/wp-toolkit/scripts ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c whmapi1 listaccts --output=json
    Feb 12 15:58:10 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:58:11 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Feb 12 15:58:11 server sudo: wp-toolkit : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/wp-toolkit/scripts ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c whmapi1 get_users_features_settings user-1=staffdir feature-1=filemanager feature-2=backup feature-3=cron feature-4=phpmyadmin feature-5=mysql feature-6=multiphp feature-7=subdomains feature-8=webprotect feature-9=wp-toolkit feature-10=wp-toolkit-deluxe --output=json
    Feb 12 15:58:11 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:58:11 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Feb 12 15:59:08 server sshd[2822]: Accepted publickey for root from 222.119.218.120 port 23199 ssh2: RSA SHA256:cnhuplyGAzI1x1W2DudZZq7CN6qi1oMqTdtdi5VqnRc
    Feb 12 15:59:08 server sshd[2822]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:59:08 server sshd[2822]: pam_lastlog(sshd:session): unable to open /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:59:10 server sshd[2828]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:59:10 server sshd[2828]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:59:50 server sshd[2876]: Accepted publickey for root from 184.94.197.2 port 63442 ssh2: RSA SHA256:ktvoarqhiUkvbQXOEOshtQttY4RN52fOmbxzT1c9U3E
    Feb 12 15:59:50 server sshd[2876]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Feb 12 15:59:50 server sshd[2876]: pam_lastlog(sshd:session): unable to open /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:59:50 server sshd[2881]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:59:50 server sshd[2881]: lastlog_openseek: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
    Feb 12 15:59:56 server useradd[2936]: new group: name=cptktywhllsifolm, GID=1006
    Feb 12 15:59:56 server useradd[2936]: new user: name=cptktywhllsifolm, UID=1004, GID=1006, home=/home/cptktywhllsifolm, shell=/bin/bash
    Feb 12 16:00:39 server sshd[3256]: Invalid user support from 178.128.152.209 port 45928
    Feb 12 16:00:39 server sshd[3256]: input_userauth_request: invalid user support [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:39 server sshd[3256]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 45928:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:39 server sshd[3256]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 45928 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:40 server sshd[3258]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 45988:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:40 server sshd[3258]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 45988 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:40 server sshd[3261]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 46018:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:40 server sshd[3261]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 46018 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:41 server sshd[3263]: Invalid user usuario from 178.128.152.209 port 46058
    Feb 12 16:00:41 server sshd[3263]: input_userauth_request: invalid user usuario [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:41 server sshd[3263]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 46058:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:41 server sshd[3263]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 46058 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:42 server sshd[3266]: Invalid user ubnt from 178.128.152.209 port 46090
    Feb 12 16:00:42 server sshd[3266]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ubnt [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:42 server sshd[3266]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 46090:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:42 server sshd[3266]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 46090 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:42 server sshd[3269]: Invalid user debian from 178.128.152.209 port 46104
    Feb 12 16:00:42 server sshd[3269]: input_userauth_request: invalid user debian [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:42 server sshd[3269]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 46104:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:42 server sshd[3269]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 46104 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:43 server sshd[3271]: Invalid user test from 178.128.152.209 port 46132
    Feb 12 16:00:43 server sshd[3271]: input_userauth_request: invalid user test [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:43 server sshd[3271]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 46132:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:43 server sshd[3271]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 46132 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:44 server sshd[3274]: Invalid user usuario from 178.128.152.209 port 46156
    Feb 12 16:00:44 server sshd[3274]: input_userauth_request: invalid user usuario [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:44 server sshd[3274]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 46156:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:44 server sshd[3274]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 46156 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:45 server sshd[3278]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 46170:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:45 server sshd[3278]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 46170 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:45 server sshd[3281]: Invalid user user from 178.128.152.209 port 46200
    Feb 12 16:00:45 server sshd[3281]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:45 server sshd[3281]: Received disconnect from 178.128.152.209 port 46200:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:00:45 server sshd[3281]: Disconnected from 178.128.152.209 port 46200 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:02:10 server polkitd[583]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3665:97728 (system bus name :1.48 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    Feb 12 16:02:10 server polkitd[583]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3665:97728 (system bus name :1.48, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
    Feb 12 16:02:17 server polkitd[583]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3711:98441 (system bus name :1.49 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    Feb 12 16:02:17 server polkitd[583]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3711:98441 (system bus name :1.49, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
    Feb 12 16:02:26 server polkitd[583]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3725:99300 (system bus name :1.50 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    Feb 12 16:02:51 server polkitd[556]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
    Feb 12 16:02:51 server polkitd[556]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
    Feb 12 16:02:51 server polkitd[556]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 2 rules
    Feb 12 16:02:51 server polkitd[556]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
    Feb 12 16:02:56 server sshd[1208]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
    Feb 12 16:02:56 server sshd[1208]: Server listening on :: port 22.
    Feb 12 16:04:58 server sshd[1703]: Connection closed by 184.94.197.2 port 52823 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:09:29 server sshd[1749]: Connection closed by 184.94.197.2 port 33422 [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:14:43 server sshd[1812]: Invalid user ubuntu from 51.254.63.223 port 33866
    Feb 12 16:14:43 server sshd[1812]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ubuntu [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:14:43 server sshd[1812]: Received disconnect from 51.254.63.223 port 33866:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
    Feb 12 16:14:43 server sshd[1812]: Disconnected from 51.254.63.223 port 33866 [preauth]
```

Please help.

Comment: I would suggest to read log manual and understand the logs and track logins and sudo command run by invalid users ports and services and close unnecessary ports or stop extra services.this link may help http://www.newfreesoft.com/linux/how_linux_log_analysis_327/

Answer (score 1):

> can secure log help finding out **how was it done**?

No.

Also, it's probably a question for security.stackexchange.com

Please consult with this discussion: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Ok, I will remove it from here and ask over there. Thank you.

Comment: @shireefkhatab https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server